# how to populate embed array of object in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I Have following model for a team

> ```
> var team = new mongoose.Schema({
>     supervisor: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'employee' }, // SupervisorId
>     commanders: [{
>         employee: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'employee' }, //under supervisor
>         level: { type: Number, defult: 1 }
>     }]
> });
> ```

while fetching data from DB I am able to populate supervisor but not employees in commanders array

I tried something like below

> ```
> db.team.findOne({
>         supervisor: employeeId
>     }).populate({
>         path: 'supervisor',
>         populate: {
>             path: 'commanders',
>             populate: {
>                 path: 'employee',
>                 model
>             }
>         }
>     })
> ```

Need help.!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with This:

```
db.team.findOne({
       supervisor: employeeId
   }).populate('supervisor commanders.employee')
```